# get iframe url and update input text

Tags: javascript, iframe, input

I have an iframe in a page and i want to get the current url for that iframe and update an input text with that url.

I found that i can get the url for the iframe using

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href

<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" src="" width="100%" height="100%" style="border-width: 0px; border-color:#ffffff; border-style: solid;" scrolling="no" border="0" class="auto-style1" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"> </iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
var link = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.location.href ;
document.Show.link.value = link;

</script>
<strong>link for the iframe :</strong>
    <input name="link" type="text" size="100" />

<a onclick="document.all.iframe.src=''" href="url" target="iframe">LINK</a>
```

that didnt work.

I dont know how to use it and update input text with that url every time the ifram's url changes

iframe url may change if some one clicks on link inside it

best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe code is wrong. There it comes :

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="url_of_your_iframe" ... ></iframe>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  document.getElementById('input').value = document.getElementById('iframe').src;
})();
</script>
```

That's it.

Edit : wait, your iframe's url changes when? how?

Comment: it changes when someone click on url like this <a onclick="document.all.iframe.src=''" href="url" target="iframe">link</a></li> it didnt change the input value,, and if someone clicks a link inside the iframe

Comment: Wow, I don't get it. Edit your original post with the anchor tag's code please.

Comment: @Florian Thanks for replying my question. I am voting for you.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: You cannot access elements of an IFRAME (including `contentWindow`) if page within the IFRAME belongs to a different domain than the parent page due to [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) (Quote from - [Yuriy Galanter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961695/yuriy-galanter))

However here's a simple and basic browser that uses keyup to search; maybe it'll come in handy for you.

If you decide to add buttons to go forward and back in history you can use `history.back();`, and `history.forward();` for that particular purpose.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>

<style type="text/css">
span.style {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    color: #666;
}

span.style:hover {
    color: #999;
}

span.style:active {
    color: #000;
}

input#goto {
    width: 80%;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

iframe#browsensearch {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#goto").click(function() {
        $(this).select();
    });

    $("#bing").click(function() {
        var sitesgohere = document.getElementById("browsensearch");
        sitesgohere.src = "http://www.bing.com/";
        $("#goto").val("bing.com");
    });

    $("#goto").keyup(function(e) {
        var val = $(this).val(), 
        sitesgohere = document.getElementById("browsensearch");

        sitesgohere.src = "http://" + val;
    });
});
</script>

<form name="sites" align="center">
    <span id="bing" class="style">Bing</span>
    <input id="goto" type="text" placeholder="http:// added by default" />
</form>

<iframe id="browsensearch" src="http://theextinctionprotocol.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/large-fireball-seen-acoss-six-midwestern-states/" width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0">
    Your browser does not support IFRAME's
</iframe>
```